# How can I figure out from which class my class is inheriting?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance

I have a DamageAccount class which looks like this:

```
@interface DamageAccount : BaseModel
{
    NSMutableArray *DamageList;
    NSDate *Time;
    NSString *Title;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *DamageList;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSDate *Time;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *Title;

@end
```

With [object class] I am getting the class name. But how can I figure out that this class inherits from BaseModel?

Is there any function for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try `isKindOfClass`

Here:

```
  [damageAccountObject isKindOfClass:[BaseModel class]]
```

Will return true

Answer (score 2):

```
[self superclass];
```

or

```
[object superclass];
```

Will give you the class that your object inherited from.

Comment: No problem Melanie, glad it helped.  Please don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you ;o)  Dave

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code of line to check the kind of the class

```
[objectInstant isKindOfClass:[(Your class name) class]]
```

put this in an if statement and it will work.